# Getting NullReferenceException from .Select() when .Count() is greater than zero LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file:

```
<Org href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/org/272521719" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.org+xml" name="blah-blah" xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1">
     <Link href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/vdc/1093121285" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.vdc+xml" name="blah-haha" rel="down"/>
     <Link href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/vdc/1213262741" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.vdc+xml" name="blah-hoho" rel="down"/>
     <Link href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/tasksList/272521719" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.tasksList+xml" rel="down"/>
     <Link href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/catalog/1309520800" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.catalog+xml" name="blah-hehe" rel="down"/>
     <Link href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/org/272521719/catalog/1309520800/controlAccess/" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.controlAccess+xml" rel="down"/>
     <Link href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/org/272521719/catalog/1309520800/action/controlAccess" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.controlAccess+xml" rel="controlAccess"/>
     <Link href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/network/1435818199" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.network+xml" name="blah-whodat" rel="down"/>
     <Link href="https://vcloudserver/api/v1.0/network/2048048931" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.network+xml" name="blah-disis" rel="down"/>
     <Description/>
     <FullName>Blah diddy Blah-Blah</FullName>
</Org>
```

So, given the following:

```
XNamespace nameSpace = "http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

When I debug the following code in VS immediate window:

```
doc.Root.Elements(nameSpace + "Link").Count()
```

I get an expected value, 8.  But when I go a little further with things using:

```
var vdcs = doc.Root.Elements(nameSpace + "Link")
  .Select(x => new vDC()
  {
    Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
    Type = x.Attribute("type").Value,
    Href = x.Attribute("href").Value
  }).Where(x=>x.Type.Contains("vdc"));
```

I am getting a NullReferenceException trying to access vdcs.Count().  I have been messing with this for too long...  I have other places where this type of thing is working fine, so that doesn't help. :(  Tried stuffing a ToList() before the Where(), and that just move the NullReferenceException up to that call.

If it helps, vDC is currently defined as:

```
public class vDC
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your links don't have a `name` - they have `rel` instead. The NPE comes from that.

You see it only when you call `Count` because the actual evaluation does not happen until then.

To change your code to guard against NPE, add a `Where` condition:

```
var vdcs = doc.Root.Elements(nameSpace + "Link")
.Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null && x.Attribute("type") != null && x.Attribute("value") != null)
.Select(x => new vDC {
    Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
    Type = x.Attribute("type").Value,
    Href = x.Attribute("href").Value
}).Where(x=>x.Type.Contains("vdc"));
```

Comment: Followed your advice, thanks!  

The schema guarantees that I will always have a name, type, and href if I look at vDCs...  So, I am applying the filter before the select and all is good!

Answer (score 2):

Some of the `Link` elements have no `name` attribute, so:

```
var vdcs = doc.Root.Elements(nameSpace + "Link")
  .Select(x => new vDC()
  {
    Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
    Type = x.Attribute("type").Value,
    Href = x.Attribute("href").Value
  }).Where(x=>x.Type.Contains("vdc"));
```

is choking on

```
Name = x.Attribute("name").Value
```

because in some cases `x.Attribute("name")` is `null`.

```
var vdcs = doc.Root.Elements(nameSpace + "Link")
  .Select(x => new 
  {
    NameAttr = x.Attribute("name"),
    TypeAttr = x.Attribute("type"),
    HrefAttr = x.Attribute("href")
  }).Select(x => new vDC()
  {
    Name = x.NameAttr == null ? null : x.NameAttr.Value,
    Type = x.TypeAttr == null ? null : x.TypeAttr.Value,
    Href = x.HrefAttr == null ? null : x.HrefAttr.Value, 
  }).Where(x=>x.Type.Contains("vdc"));
```

or similar should fix things.

Comment: Moved the Where() to before the Select():  

    `var vdcs = doc.Root.Elements(nameSpace + "Link")
       .Where(x => x.Attribute("type").Value.Contains("vdc"))
       .Select(x => new vDC()
       {
          Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
          Type = x.Attribute("type").Value,
          Href = x.Attribute("href").Value
       });`